# ON_COMMAND_RANGE value to memory mapping fails?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Unhandled Exception... Access Violation  with an array for a callback?

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(yoda, CDialog)
    ON_COMMAND_RANGE(2000, 2009, OnChannelClick)


BOOL yoda::OnInitDialog()
{
    chbxChannel = new CButton[10];

    CString s;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        (chbxChannel + i) -> Create("", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX, CRect(80-50,  100+i*20, 100-50,  120+i*20), this, 2000+i);


        s.Format("%d",(chbxChannel + nID) -> GetCheck()); // <-- Works fine
        MessageBox(s);

    }
}


void yoda::OnChannelClick(UINT nID)
{
    CString s;
    s.Format("%d",nID);// values for nID are correct
    MessageBox(s);

    s.Format("%d",(chbxChannel + nID) -> GetCheck()); //??  <-- Unhandled Exception... Access Violation  ?????
    MessageBox(s);
}
```

- For some reason the address offset for the pointer in the callback does not match the instantiation offset address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDs range from 2000 to 2009, but your array is from 0 to 9. You need to subtract the start of the range for use as an array index.